# Find the most recent file in a directory without reading all the contents of it

Tags: python, c, unix

I'm trying to find out the latest file in a huge filesystem. One way to do this is to go through all directories - one at a time, read its contents, select the latest file etc.

The obvious drawback is I have to get *all* the files in a specific directory. I was wondering whether there was a 'magic' call in Python [1] which Unix supports to get just the latest file in a directory.

[1]. My application is in Python, but if a readymade solution doesnt exist in stdlib, please provide C (lanuage) alternatives using system calls. I'm willing to write a C-extension and make this work.

Thanks

**update**: I suppose I should offer an explanation on why an inotify type solution wont work for me. I was simply looking for a system call using Python/C which could give me the latest file. Yes, one could have inotify (or a similar overarching setup) which monitors FS changes but given a random directory how do I find the latest file is the essence of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not believe that generically 'Unix' or Posix systems support a platform independent file system change notification.

That said, there are lots of unixy systems that do:

- OS X

  - [FSEvents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
  - [fslogger](https://web.archive.org/web/20200502165655/http://osxbook.com/software/fslogger/)
  - [DTrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) + syscall
  - [pnotify](https://web.archive.org/web/20100808023357/http://mark.heily.com:80/pnotify/)
  - [Kqueue](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2)
- Linux:

  - [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)
  - [pnotify](https://web.archive.org/web/20100808023357/http://mark.heily.com:80/pnotify/)
  - [epoll](https://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman7/epoll.7.html)
- Solaris

  - DTrace
- BSD

  - pnotify
  - [Kqueue](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2)
- Python:

  - [Kqueue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#kqueue-objects) is directly supported in Python only on BSD
  - [Pyinotify](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyinotify/) only on Linux
  - [FSEvents](https://pypi.org/project/pyobjc-framework-FSEvents/2.2b2/) only on Darwin / OS X
  - [Gamin](https://web.archive.org/web/20210308133329/https://people.gnome.org/%7Eveillard/gamin/python.html) only on Linux and BSD

Others have suggested trying to interpret `ls`. Don't do that. If you feel compelled to use a Unix tool, most Unix / Linux / Posix flavors also have `stat` as a utility. The [stat utility](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stat-invocation.html#stat-invocation) has configurable output and you can set the fields that you want to parse.  It is part of the GNU core utilities.

Comment: GNU stat has configurable output, yes -- POSIX stat does not, and (for that matter) is quite tricky to parse.

Comment: Sadly, Looks like the answer to my question is a nope, Posix systems doesnt have that functionality.

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered using [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) which can watch a directory and subdirectories?
This might require your code to be threaded, say, a watcher thread that records the latest changes for the main thread to poll.

Alternatively, you could use popen and get the result of 'ls -t | head -1'

Comment: +1 for the inotify suggestion, but the ls suggestion doesn't avoid the expensive read (and is also evil -- ls isn't guaranteed to emit script-usable, as opposed to human-readable, filenames; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Using inotify requires having a daemon process running at all times, and you'll have to do a full search to sync up if anything changes while your daemon isn't running.  ls isn't relevant--it can't do anything you can't do better with a real API.

Comment: Glenn, sure -- but it doesn't have to be *your* program that is running as a daemon; incron, for instance, can take that job off your hands.

Comment: The 'ls' suggestion is pretty much a kludge but given the OP's question ('.. without reading all the contents of it'), it's a suggestion that moves the work from his code to the commands used in popen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately pyinotify doesnt work well with NFS - which is the setup I have. Works great with local mounts but as soon as I get to NFS mounts - it simply wont.

Comment: Also I cannot have a long running process monitoring the directories. The requirement is a call which gives me the result. I appreciate to response but pyinotify/inotify wasnt what I was looking for.

Comment: @Martin Thomas - Right. The question was not how to avoid reading the contents *directly*, but how to avoid reading the contents. If you've dealt with directories large enough to take a minute or so to parse and stat the inodes, you'd appreciate why using ls -t is unacceptable for this use. (More than that, ls -t is actually *slower* than doing it yourself, as it's doing a full sort rather than simply looking for the single newest/oldest item... and also see the contents of the link I provided earlier).

Comment: @Jeffery - "WAYTTD" (What Are You Trying To Do) is a very appropriate question here -- if you're specifying an immediate step you want to be able to take, we're only able to guess at the larger goal you're trying to achieve and the constraints on that goal. Barring more accurate specification of your _real_ problem, inotify was a very good guess -- and may be helpful to other people asking the same question, when an answer to a different question would actually be more useful to them. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @Charles, sorry about that. Unfortunately inotify type solution wasnt what I was looking for. I *cant* keep a long running process running which keeps a tab of what's happening on the FS. My application gets run and can only query the FS using Python/C for latest file - and I thought my question was complete. I'll edit the question to include this.

Answer (score 3):

No portable API exists to do this in Unix.  Most filesystems don't index files inside directories by their mtime (or ctime), so even if it did it probably wouldn't be any faster than doing it yourself.

Answer (score -3):

You don't have to use Python for this task, wrap python over the Unix utilities which understand filesystem better and can give you this information.
For e.g.

Do `ls -ltr |tail -1` on that directory and the result would be string, split that and get the last item which would be file you are looking for.

```
import subprocess
targetdir = 'foo'
#ls -ltr |tail -1

list_reverse = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-t',targetdir],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tail_call = subprocess.Popen(['head','-1'],stdin=list_reverse.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = tail_call.communicate()
print out.split()[-1]
```

Comment: This still reads the entire contents of the directory. Also, it's evil; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: I thought, the OP did not want to read the contents of the files in the directory, and was okay with listing the directory. Good link on evils of ls. Had not known earlier. Thanks.

Comment: Woo.. inotify based suggestion is the only thing to go for.

Comment: Off the top of my head, wouldn't 'ls -t | head -1' be better because it could quit after the first entry was read? Wouldn't 'tail -1' require the subprocess to wait until the entire directory was read.

Comment: Martin: Yes, I realize ls -t | head -1 would be better. Due to my constant usage of ls -ltr, my fingers typed those. Thanks.

Comment: Senthil, I do the same .. nearly posted it earlier.