# Use Python to Optimally find Top 10 recently created files

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to find a optimal way of extracting most recently, say 10, created files from a directory tree using Python. I've found a number[1, 2] of interesting solutions, however, they only involved a single file.

```
                      ├── d1
                      │   ├── d1-1
                      │   ├── d1-1
                      :
                      ├── d2
                      │   ├── d2-1
                      │   └── d2-2
                      │   │   ├── f1.xxx
                      : :
                      │   │   ├── fn.xxx
                      ├── d3
                      │   ├── d3-1
                      :
                      :
```

The only way I can think of doing that, at the moment, is iteratively appending results by looping through the same tree until I have desired 10 results; the problem with this approach is that it will clearly be time consuming... especially that my directory trees may be huge. An alternative solution I thought about involves parsing an entire directory tree and generating file name paths with their corresponding creation or modification dates and then possibly use that 'index' file to get top 10 recent files. A database would have perhaps been useful here, however, it's not an option at the moment.

Does anyone know of an optimal way of achieving this?

[1] [Python return filepath/filename of most recent csv file stored in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11900038/664424)
[2] [Find the most recent file in a directory without reading all the contents of it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4709968/664424)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a generator function to return the creation time and the filename, and use the `heapq` module to automatically keep track of the latest 'n' entries rather efficiently - example:

```
import os
import heapq

def iterfiles(root):
    for base, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            fullname = os.path.join(base, filename)
            yield os.stat(fullname).st_ctime, fullname

print heapq.nlargest(10, iterfiles('some path here'))
```

Just an aside - you may have to handle an `IOError` (a try/except around the yield) if permissions aren't available to stat the file.

Comment: Thank you for this; upto what point would such an approach be able to scale? I have ~2million files in one of my directory tree. Would it makes sense to perhaps write results from iterfiles to disk or can I do that in memory?

Comment: @phiri, iterfiles doesn't store all the information in memory at once. It passes one file at a time to the heapq. The OS _will_ have to look up the creation time of each file though, which will take a while for 2 million files.

Comment: @gnibbler, thank you for that; I guess I might have to go through the heapq algorithm (http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html) to fully comprehend how that all works out.

Comment: note: ctime is the creation time only on Windows, on other platforms it shows when the last time the file metadata has changed

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thank you for the heads up; just from going through this (http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/20526-mtime-ctime-atime.html)... is there a reliable platform independent way of getting the actual creation time?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Good point - maybe `OSError` then `IOError` if handling needed to be different - or just `EnvironmentError` if you didn't care

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import heapq

basedir = ???

files = (os.path.join(x[0], fn) for x in os.walk(basedir) for fn in x[2])
print heapq.nlargest(10, files, key=lambda x:os.stat(x).st_ctime)
```